# How to pipeline batch script output to a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, apache, powershell, batch-file

I need to use HTTP Apache piped logging to place all entries with response code "400" into a separate file. For that, I want to use PowerShell `Select-String` since it is the closest thing to the `grep` command in Linux:

I have the following batch to call a PowerShell script from within a cmd environment:

```
powershell -command "& { sls ,400, 'cmd -ca | select -exp line >> access_400.log }"
```

As far as I know, the "CustomLog" in httpd will be similar to this:

```
CustomLog "| 'call_powershell_script_that_will_extract_400_entries.ps1' " common
```

How can I make the piped output of CustomLog be input to the PowerShell script that will extract the entries with "400" response code?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not doing this entirely in PowerShell? Other than an irresistible urge to make your life more complicated than it needs to be, I mean.

Comment: I thought that after the "|" needs to be batch file, did not know that it also accepts powershell scripts

Anyway I got the script working outside of the CustomLog, but when I use it with it, the output.log gets locked and the error.log in apache gets filled with "file cannot be opened because it is used being used by another process"

Comment: Would it be easier to just write ALL entries to a single log file and then grab the 400 entries that you care about from the general log file? I feel like this would be a better solution that trying to write something crazy into an Apache config file, but could be mistaken. Also, the work is MUCH simpler with PowerShell at that point. It's just "Get-Content httpRoot\logs\*.log | Select-String -Pattern 400", which can also be run as a scheduled job if you wanted to do it that way. It's also probably better to have the logs change the name after a day or so.

Comment: @PSGuy

That is pretty much the plan B I have at the moment. The issue with making it a PowerShell script is performance. The access.log I have could be in GBs. With PowerShell, this will take a very long time. I'm currently making a simple java program to handle this process of reading and filtering the access.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [automatic PowerShell variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), `$input`, in your script.

I don't totally understand your script, but you should be able to extrapolate this similar example:

##### `filter.bat`

```
@powershell -command "$input | select-string -casesensitive -pattern '%1' | select-object -expandproperty line | out-file -append -encoding ASCII output.log"
```

`$input` will be filled with the console input for the BAT/CMD file.

To test, from the command line, use `dir | filter.bat ".exe"`, then `type output.log`.

Notably, I'm using out-file instead of the powershell redirection operator so that the output file is not encoded in the powershell default, UTF-16, but as a more generally usable ASCII file.

Comment: Thank you very much. By testing on the CMD, it works as I need. But when I use it in the CustomLog in apache httpd.conf, for some reason, I keep having script is failing because it cannot open the output.log file because it is being used by another process...

I'm trying to solve this but not sure how... do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much for the script earlier!

Comment: I don't have knowledge (or a setup) of all those components working together, but I would first try moving the log file out of the powershell script like so `@powershell -command "$input | select-string -casesensitive -pattern '%1' | select-object -expandproperty line" >> output.log`.