# Powershell: Pipe keystroke to interactive program

Tags: bash, powershell, svn

I'm looking for a bash-equivalent for the Pipe, i.e., `echo 't' | svn [...]` in powershell. I'd like to automatically checkout data from a subversion repository whose certificate is not trusted by default. When invoking the command on powershell, the program asks for a user input, where I'd select `'t'`. The command line for the svn call is

```
svn checkout --no-auth-cache <repo>
```

which brings up the query

```
(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily?
```

After pressing 't', svn checks out the data.

However, if I invoke

```
echo 't' | svn checkout --no-auth-cache <repo>
```

The svn call fails just like hitting an other key than 't' on the query. I guess this automization should work somehome but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any hints?

Comment: Hi, maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483568/how-to-pipeline-batch-script-output-to-a-powershell-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Uninstall Software that has prompts for user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650913/powershell-uninstall-software-that-has-prompts-for-user-input)

Comment: This question is better but an answer is in the other one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pipeline batch script output to a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483568/how-to-pipeline-batch-script-output-to-a-powershell-script)